# Readability of Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON OBJECT similar to following

```
{
  "kay1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":{
    "key31":"value31",
    "key32":"value32",
    "key33":"value33"
  }
}
```

I want to replace that with JSON ARRAY as follows

```
[
  "value1",
  "value2",
  [
    "value31",
    "value32",
    "value33"
  ]
]
```

My motivation to change the the JSON OBJECT to JSON ARRAY is it takes less amount of network traffic, getting the value from ARRAY is efficient than OBJECT, etc.

One problem I face is the readability of the ARRAY is very less than OBJECT.

Is there any way to improve the readability?

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: "Readability" is a subjective matter. Both cases are OK. Especially with the help of modern debugging tools

Comment: Seems like microoptimization for the sake of it. I'd worry more about choosing the right data structure. Arrays and objects are used to represent different things.

Comment: What's less readable about the array?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli  the less readable thing is at the time of access,

eg, for access an object is like Object.key1 or Object.key3.key31, etc

for Array it is like Array[0], Array[2][0], etc

Comment: @Ashim How is Array[2][0] less readable than Object.key3.key31? The second one is just more typing. But I think this question is pointless. You should use an object when it makes sense to use an object, and an array when it makes sense to use an array. You should not choose one or the other because one of them takes up a little less bandwidth.

Comment: @Ashim I suggest to write wrapper methods to access array data and keep your code readable. I think it make sense to work with arrays if someone care about traffic regarding to high traffic in sense of high frequenced requests and\or large amount of JSON data.

Comment: thanks @StephanAhlf , I think it will work for me. But I like to have little more,

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I have written a function which will convert all instances of object to array and give you the result you are expecting.

```
var objActual = {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":{
    "key31":"value31",
    "key32":"value32",
    "key33": {
      "key331" : "value331",
      "key332" : "value332"
    }
  }
};


ObjectUtil = {
  isObject : function(variable) {
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(variable) === '[object Object]') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  convertToArray : function(obj) {
     var objkeys = Object.keys(obj);
     var arr = [];
     objkeys.forEach(function(key) {
        var objectToPush;
        if(ObjectUtil.isObject(obj[key])) {
           objectToPush = ObjectUtil.convertToArray(obj[key]);
        } else {
           objectToPush = obj[key];
        }
        arr.push(objectToPush);
     });
     return arr;
  }
};

var result = ObjectUtil.convertToArray(objActual);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: My problem is to access the Array with more readable format, actually the index value 0,1, 2 does not says anything what is inside the array, is there any way which I can used to make the access of array more readable

Comment: Readable as in ? what you want to achieve ? Any example you can quote ?

Comment: Lets say Home is an object, Home.numberOfRooms says number of rooms of the Home object, but If I save Home as a array and Home[0] provides the number of rooms, its works but for a programmer it is very complex to work with an array

Comment: You can still use key with Array. You know your javascript Array doesn't only have index as key. You can get home.numberOfRooms or home['numberOfRooms'] even when home is an array, you can have numberOfRooms as key. If you dont believe , you can try urself.

Comment: In this way my actual problem remains, I want to reduce the network traffic and optimise the performance

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be:

```
{
  "kay1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":["value31", "value32", "value33"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the init method is time critical. So use a scheme or assign static JSON to `Storage.keys` and assign your bulk data array to `store.data`.   You can use `store.get("key3.key31")` after that. http://jsfiddle.net/2o411k00/

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp*/)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
    }

    return res;
  };
}


var data = {
  "kay1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key3":{
    "key31":"value31",
    "key32":"value32",
    "key33":"value33"
  }
}


var Storage = function(data){
    this.rawData = data;
    return this;
}

Storage.prototype.init = function(){
    var self = this;
    var index = 0;
    var mp = function(dat, rootKey){

        var res = Object.keys(dat).map(function(key, i) {
            var v = dat[key];
            if (typeof(v) === 'object'){
                mp(v, key);
            } else {
                self.data.push(v);
                var nspace = rootKey.split(".").concat([key]).join(".");
                self.keys[nspace] = index++;
            }
        });
    }
    mp(this.rawData, "");
}

Storage.prototype.get = function(key){
    return this.data[this.keys[key]];
};

Storage.prototype.data = [];
Storage.prototype.keys = {};

var store = new Storage(data);
console.log(data);
store.init();
console.log("keys", store.keys);
console.log("data", store.data);

console.log("kay1=", store.get(".kay1"));
console.log("key2=", store.get(".key2"));
console.log("key3.key31=", store.get("key3.key31"));
console.log("key3.key32=",store.get("key3.key32"));
console.log("key3.key33=", store.get("key3.key33"));
```